# Twitter-bootstrap 3 affixed sidebar menu is not displayed fulled when scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I am having problems with an sidebar menu when scroll down full menu is not getting displayed.tired adding z-index still facing the problem example :i add z-index:1 then footer is overlapped

Below i have pasted the code.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y2m596db/2)

```
<header class="masthead">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="pull-right hidden-sm">
                    <h1><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> <i
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<!-- Begin Body -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="list-group" id="sidebar">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                    Link 1
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 2
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 3
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 4
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 5
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                    Link 1
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 2
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 3
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 4
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 5
                </a><a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                    Link 1
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 2
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 3
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 4
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 5
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h2>Content</h2>
            Totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
            dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
            cor magni dolores
            eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
            consectetur, adipisci velit,
            sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
            Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex
            ea commodi consequatur?

            <hr class="col-md-12">

            <h2>Content</h2>
            Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
            dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
            cor magni dolores
            eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
            consectetur, adipisci velit,
            sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
            Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut

            <hr class="col-md-12">

            <h2>Content</h2>
            Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
            dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
            cor magni dolores
            eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
            consectetur, adipisci velit,
            sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
            Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut

            <hr class="col-md-12">

            <h2>Content</h2>
            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
            totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
            dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
            cor magni dolores
            eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
            consectetur, adipisci velit,
            sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
            Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut

            <h2>Content</h2>
            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
            totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
            dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
            cor magni dolores
            eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
            consectetur, adipisci velit,
            sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
            Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut</footer>
```

**JS**

```
$('#sidebar').affix({
    offset: {
      top: $('header').height()
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
navbar-form input, .form-inline input {
    width:auto;
}

header {
    height:10px;
}

@media (min-width: 979px) {
    #sidebar.affix-top {
      position: static;
      margin-top:25px;
      width:228px;
    }

    #sidebar.affix {
      position: fixed;
      top:25px;
      width:228px;z-index:1

    }
}

.affix,.affix-top {
    position:static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add priority to your sidebar using z-index.

```
#sidebar.affix {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/y2m596db/1/)

Comment: its not working tried . i have repeated menu 3 times  but only 2  is been displayed